# Почему переменная не преобразовывается в тип float?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код Python:

```
p = int(input())
x = (input())
y = (input())
sum = (x+'.'+y)
float(sum)
yearsum = sum*p
print(sum,yearsum)
```

Входные данные:

```
12
179
0
```

Выходные:

```
179.0 179.0179.0179.0179.0179.0179.0179.0179.0179.0179.0179.0179.0
```

Т.е. получается строка. Почему `sum` не преобразовывается в тип `float`? Нельзя делать с этой переменной никаких действий, хотя обозначил `float(sum)`

Comment: unrelated: `sum` является встроенной функцией в Питоне -- избегайте использовать это имя для своих переменных.

Answer (score 8):

Потому что строка `float(sum)` не изменит значение самой переменной `sum`, для этого надо присвоить значение другой переменной (либо этой же):

```
sum = float(sum)
```

А так у Вас вывелось данное значение, а потом Вы умножили строку на число, получив повтор строки, то есть:

```
>>>print('179.0' * 12)
179.0179.0179.0179.0179.0179.0179.0179.0179.0179.0179.0179.0
```

Answer (score 6):

Потому, что функция float не меняет исходное значение в переменной, а возвращает результат преобразования.

```
p = int(input())
x = (input())
y = (input())
sum = (x+'.'+y)
sum = float(sum) /*присваивание для изменения значения*/
yearsum = sum*p
print(sum,yearsum)
```